# How to store different username-password key pair in SSH in GIT Bash?

Tags: git, bash, ssh, passwords

Current Machine: Git Bash on Windows.

Trying to connect to a Mac through SSH.

When I execute the below command:

```
ssh aisong@10.209.161.253 "ls"
Password: <myPassword>
```

Output (works as desired):

```
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Library
Movies
Music
Pictures
Public
```

Note: My username for gitbash is different from 'aisong'. Similarly, the password for my username is different from 'myPassword' used above for the username 'aisong'.

How do I store this password (myPassword) for the username 'aisong' permanently so that it doesn't prompt for a password next time I execute the above ssh command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the password, use ssh keys. Follow the steps mentioned here:

```
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/
```

Only in place of add SSH key to the github account, add it to the MAC. To add key to the MAC, follow the steps mentioned here:

```
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/make-passwordless-ssh-connection-osx-10-9-mavericks-linux/
```

You want to add the public key generated on the GIT bash to the authorized_keys file. Let me know if you need further help.